# Prove that: $\underset{x\to \infty }{\text{lim}}\frac{x+\sin (x) \cos (x)}{e^{\sin (x)} (x+\sin (x) \cos (x))} = \text{doesn't exist}$

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis

Prove that:
$$\underset{x\to \infty }{\text{lim}}\frac{x+\sin (x) \cos (x)}{e^{\sin (x)} (x+\sin (x) \cos (x))} = \text{doesn't exist}$$

We were showing that the limit doesn't exist with L'hopital rule: We have done L'hopital 4 times and then seen that the zero in the denominator is not isolated (the epsilon neighbourhood of the zero contained another zero).

I understand that $e^{\sin{x}}$ is oscillating and bounded,however, I do not really understand why the $e^{\sin{x}}$ is "stronger" the $x$, since it is bounded and the limit is not one.

Another question is, how valid is a proof with L'hopital rulle used to proof that the limit doesn't exist.

Comment: is everything typed correctly? the numerator and the denominator have some common factor to cancel out isn't it?

Comment: @SiongThyeGoh oh I see, we were doing this problem during lectures and looks like nobody noticed that it can be canceled...

Comment: $$\frac{x+\sin (x) \cos (x)}{e^{\sin (x)} (x+\sin (x) \cos (x))} = e^{-\sin(x)}\Rightarrow\text{indeterminate as $x\to\infty$}.$$

Answer (score 1):

Let me point out two misconceptions:

1. I cannot say for sure, but I expect that *the proof using de l'Hospital's rule* you're mentioning is false. Simply because it's a theorem of the type *if (...) then the limit exists*, and not of the type *if (...) the the limit doesn't exist*.
2. You may consider this picky, but one shouldn't write
   $$\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x) = \text{doesn't exist},$$
   but rather
   $$\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x) \quad \text{doesn't exist}.$$
   The difference lies in the fact that $\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x)$ is a priori just a symbol. If the limit exists, we can assign a value to this symbol and write $\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x) = (\ldots)$. But when the limit doesn't exist, the symbol is not related to any number, and writing an equal sign next to it is misleading.

---

As for the problem itself, it's helpful to note that
$$
\frac{x+\sin (x) \cos (x)}{e^{\sin (x)} (x+\sin (x) \cos (x))}
= e^{-\sin x}
$$
for all $x$ for which the first expression makes sense. This reduces the problem to the study of $e^{-\sin x}$, or even $\sin x$.